# How to create a subset of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have two tables (`delta` and `aa`) of flight data, and I am trying to create a new table that would be a subset of `delta`. This subset would only contain the rows in delta that share the same `origin_airport_id` and `dest_airport_id` as in `aa`.

`aa` has 89,940 rows and `delta` has 245,052. 
I used:

```
CREATE TABLE dl_share 
AS 
SELECT delta.* 
FROM delta,aa 
WHERE (aa.origin_airport_id = delta.origin_airport_id 
  AND aa.dest_airport_id = delta.dest_airport_id)
```

which creates a table with 18,562,876 rows. Why is the size of the table bigger rather than smaller, and how can I do this correctly?

Comment: You are joining two tables that's why. Anyway you should use `JOIN` syntax. Is your code complete because there is no `dl1` alias?

Comment: try using a `select distinct`.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do? There are a few rows that are the same (different flights but you have the same origin and destination) and I want to include all of them. And I did mean dl when I put dl1.

Comment: Your query will throw an error because there is no table or alias called dl1.

Comment: -fixed and still outputs a much larger table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `WHERE EXISTS` rather than `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM delta d
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM aa 
    WHERE aa.origin_airport_id = d.origin_airport_id 
    AND aa.dest_airport_id = d.dest_airport_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
SELECT delta.* 
FROM delta
inner join aa on aa.origin_airport_id = delta.origin_airport_id
and aa.dest_airport_id = delta.dest_airport_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting what you want with a view then try 'create' on it.

Try this modification of your code:

```
 CREATE TABLE dl_share AS SELECT delta.*,aa.* FROM delta,aa WHERE
 (aa.origin_airport_id = delta.origin_airport_id AND aa.dest_airport_id
 = delta.dest_airport_id)
```

Make sure you get primary and foreign key right.

Hope it works